# how to resolve OracleTypes.CURSOR type

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I am using ojdbc14, version : 10.2.0.4.0, but not able to get OracleTypes.CURSOR while fetching procedure using JDBC in java.

```
try {
      CallableStatement callBackStmt = null;
      CIDBConnector dao = new CIDBConnector();
       connection = dao.getConnection();
        callBackStmt = connection.prepareCall(query);
        callBackStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        callBackStmt.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        boolean hasMoreResultList =  callBackStmt.execute();

        if(hasMoreResultList){
          ResultSet resultSet = null;

         System.out.print("fetching result from procedure");

         resultSet = (java.sql.ResultSet)callBackStmt.getObject(1);
           while(resultSet.next()){
          //setting the resultModel
              ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
                resultModel.setLOR_NO(resultSet.getString(1));
              resultModel.setORDER_NO(resultSet.getString(2));
            resultModel.setINSERT_TIMESTAMP(resultSet.getTimestamp(3));
              resultModel.setORDER_XML_TIMESTAMP(resultSet.getTimestamp(4));
             resultModel.setMTAS_XML_TIMESTAMP(resultSet.getTimestamp(5));
                 resultModel.setCALLBACK_TIMESTAMP(resultSet.getTimestamp(6));
              resultModel.setAAA_REQUIRED(resultSet.getString(7));

             //adding to the list
            modelList.add(resultModel);
         }
            resultSet = (java.sql.ResultSet)callBackStmt.getObject(2);
```

Comment: connection = dao.getConnection(); what are you getting?

Comment: ojdbc14 is for **Java 1.4**, you may want to try a version of the driver for more recent versions of Java.

Comment: Try `resultSet =  ((OracleCallableStatement)callBackStmt).getCursor(1);`

Comment: What is your query? Refer to RefCursorInSample.java (https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/AdvancedSamples/RefCursorInSample.java) for example.

Comment: through the dao.getConnection() , I am getting the a new jdbc connection

Comment: thank you mark I changed the version , its working now. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: Thank you for your example @Nirmala